# Xamarin forms sqlite Async await not wait the process

Tags: c#, sqlite, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

because it does not respect the await

```
public async Task Save(Ticket header, TicketLines newLines)
{
                Debug.WriteLine("init save");
                await dbConnection.RunInTransactionAsync(new Action<SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection>(tran =>
                {
                    dbConnection.InsertAsync(header).ContinueWith((t) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("-> New header ID: {0}", header.Id);                       
                        foreach (var item in newLines)
                        {
                            item.DocumentId = = header.Id;
                        }
                        dbConnection.InsertAllAsync(newLines);                     
                    });
                    //tran.Commit();                    
                }));
                Debug.WriteLine("End Save");

}
```

Order debug

1. init save

   2. End save  sds
   3. ->New header ID: 1

Comment: maybe because it doesn't understand what you're trying to do ...meaning please edit this and ask a real question..

Comment: You don't actually await anything in the delegate itself.

Answer (score -1):

you have two async calls that are not being awaited (you don't have the await keyword before them)

```
public Save(Ticket header, TicketLines newLines) {
            Debug.WriteLine("init save");
             dbConnection.RunInTransactionAsync(new Action<SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection>(tran =>
            {
                 dbConnection.Insert(header).ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("-> New header ID: {0}", header.Id);                       
                    foreach (var item in newLines)
                    {
                        item.DocumentId = = header.Id;
                    }
                     dbConnection.InsertAll(newLines);                     
                });
                //tran.Commit();                    
            }));
            Debug.WriteLine("End Save");
```

}

Comment: i have just copied part of his code and added the await, but i can add the rest to make the answer more understandable if you want.

Comment: I can not implement a transaction, in the event of an error abort all insert

Comment: ok, reading your question i see that you have writed the log of the debug output.

init save -> End save sds -> New header ID: 1.

that is what the await do, it let the function running and continue with the Current execution, what do you to do? run it linearly?

Comment: I will explain.
I have the UI button Save, and i need to save the records, and only after recording all registration and refreshment screen.

What me this happens is that as the  Async Task Save waits for the inclusion of all the record I refreshment screen but still do not have the records in the database

Comment: well, you can achieve that if you remove the async and the task fromyour method definition and remove the await statements, but your ui will be freezed while the transaction is done.

Comment: what you can do is show a spinner animation and only refresh when the transactions is done.

Comment: no problem add animation,but the problem is RunInTransactionAsync no respect wait for all inserts... in buton Save use await _repository.Save(Header, Lines);

Comment: that is becouse the await method just "mark" the task to be executed in paralel and continue, remove the await from there and the rest of the code will not be executed until the transaction is done

Comment: i have edited the answer to show you what i mean. i have deleted the Async from insertAsync and inertAllAsync becouse i guess that they have a sync variation, if not just call the Async version without await, the code will be executed synchronously then.